# Laravel 5 intervention The requested resource someImage.jpg was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel 5 and I have problem.

If I try to pass image to the route like this

```
http:://localhost/someImage.jpg
```

and route is like:

```
Route::get('/{filename}', function($filename){

    $img = Image::make(storage_path($filename))->resize(50, 50);
    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

It returns The requested resource someImage.jpg was not found on this server.

If i call it like

```
http:://localhost/someImage
```

and my route is

```
Route::get('/{filename}', function($filename){

    $img = Image::make(storage_path($filename . ('.jpg')))->resize(50, 50);
    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

image can be displayed.

How can I make first example working?

I am not sure but I think that it is trying to access image directly instead to pass it to the route, and that i need to change some config to prevent it. Maybe in htaccess?

.htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Show us your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is available in your storage directory because you're using storage_path() method.